# Disable Ember.Logger.log() in production build from code

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I want to disable all the logs while building production build. I am using ember 2.5 latest version.

Comment: Are you building with `environment production`? Ember debug doesn't get included

Comment: I am running `ember build` from terminal.

Comment: `ember build --environment=production`

Comment: @Kitler does it remove code from files ?

Answer (score 2):

What I can think of for a quick solution is the following.

adding the following, to something like app.js or an initializer maybe

```
if(config.environment === 'production'){
  Ember.Logger.log = function(){}
}
```

and maybe going a bit further by adding an option to your config/environment.

```
  var ENV = {
    logging_active: false,
  ...,
  ...,
  }
  if (environment === 'development') {
    ENV.logging_active = true
  }
```

and then in your app

```
if(!config.logging_active){
  Ember.Logger.log = function(){}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking same. But I want to disable all log, assert, debug, warning, error messages. Do ember have any core functions to handle this ?

Comment: Quickly had a look at https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.5.0/packages/ember-metal/lib/logger.js#L50 and other involved code. Can't really see anything that suggests it will be possible, to do something like Ember.Logger.disable().

Comment: I think assigning method to empty function is the only way to solve it now

Comment: This could be a nice to have in the framework actually, like LOG_TRANSITIONS etc in config/environment, but something like LOG_DEV_ONLY

Comment: Yes may be we can create an issue in emberjs project

Comment: then again, even better would be a process via ember-cli that just removes all those references throughout the codebase, not sure. Drop on by the slack community and suggest it ? I think it could be useful

Comment: Don't create an issue in the Ember.js project, as this is an Ember CLI feature. There is an Ember CLI addon being developed to strip code from production builds which you will be able to use for this purpose.

Comment: `Ember.Logger` methods are already disabled for production builds.

Comment: @locks I don't think this is mentioned in docs, would you recommend a PR ?

Comment: The addon I mentioned previously is [ember-cli-defeatureify](https://github.com/jkarsrud/ember-cli-defeatureify).

Comment: @TameBadger that's a good idea, add the info to https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/configuring-ember/debugging/.

Comment: @locks does it removes log from code ? what will be good solution ?